# Speeding up Gaussian expectations

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

I found that Mathematica's Expectation operator is slow for Gaussian random variables, I'd like to scale to 100 dimensions, but it currently takes 10 seconds for 10 dimensions, looking forward to tips on how to speed this up.

Problem: for a Gaussian random variable $x$ in $d$ dimensions, compute the following quantities
$$E[xx'],E[xx'xx'],E[xx'\otimes xx']$$

$\otimes$ refers to KroneckerProduct

````
CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct;

problemSetup[d_] := (
   cov = DiagonalMatrix@Table[1/k, {k, 1, d}];
   dist = MultinormalDistribution[N@cov];
   Clear[x];
   xvec = Array[x, d];
   X2 = Expectation[xvec\[CircleTimes]xvec, 
     xvec \[Distributed] dist];
   X2X2 = 
    Expectation[(xvec\[CircleTimes]xvec).(xvec\[CircleTimes]xvec),
      xvec \[Distributed] dist]; 
   X4 = Expectation[Outer[Times, xvec, xvec, xvec, xvec], 
     xvec \[Distributed] dist];
   X4flat = Flatten[X4, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}];
   );
problemSetup[10] // Timing (* {10.3734, Null} *)
```
````

Comment: Are more general covariance matrices to be considered?  What you've described are independent normal distributions with mean zero and different variances.

Comment: Just fiddling, I've gotten the time eater (X4) from 11.7 sec to 0.03 sec. Doing it for 100 takes about 5 minutes. Is that fast enough for your needs?

Comment: @jimb just zero centered Gaussians with arbitrary diagonal covariances (since any covariance matrix is diagonal in some coordinate system), ciao I was hoping for 5 seconds...

Comment: Just getting `Outer[Times, xvec, xvec, xvec, xvec]` probably takes 2 minutes with `d=100`.  I suspect that @ciao is using the following:  `AbsoluteTiming[Outer[Times, xvec, xvec, xvec, xvec] /. {x[k_]^4 -> 3/k^2, x[k_]^3 -> 0, x[k_]^2 -> 1/k, x[k_] -> 0};]`.

Comment: Dropping `x[k_]^3 -> 0` from the replacement list gives the same answer and shaves off just a little bit of time.

Comment: Well, the following command takes 2 seconds, and it's operating on a quantity with a lot less zeros -- `d = 100; A = ConstantArray[1, {d^2, d^2}]; A + A // Timing // First`

Comment: I think perhaps the last quantity would be too much work, but `E[xx'xx']` should be doable in a couple of seconds

Comment: Agreed.  Using `(xvec\[TensorProduct]xvec).(xvec\[TensorProduct]xvec) /. {x[k_]^4 -> 
   3/k^2, x[k_]^2 -> 1/k, x[k_] -> 0}` takes about 3 seconds when `d=100`.

Comment: Might want to change TensorProduct to CircleTimes here?

Comment: good point....as extra bonus, halirutan's editor plug-in turns it into ⊗ symbols which work as expected when pasting back into Mathematica!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Identities allow computing these matrices 100s of times faster
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
P_d&=&\text{nsymm[d], the symmetrizer matrix}\\
\mu&=&E[x]\\
X^2&=&E[xx']\\
E[(xx')(xx')]&=& (\text{Tr} X^2) X^2 + 2X ^2 X^2 -2\|\mu\|^2 \mu \mu'\\
E[xx'\otimes xx']&=&2P_d( X^2\otimes X^2) + \text{vec} X^2 (\text{vec} X^2)'-2(\mu \mu')\otimes (\mu \mu')
\\
E[(x^Tx)^2]& =& E[\|x\|^4] = (\text{Tr} X^2)^2 + 2 \text{Tr} X^2 X^2 -2\|\mu\|^4
\end{eqnarray}
$$

```
(* Symmetrizer matrix, see \
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230167/commutation-\
symmetrizer-and-duplication-matrices *)

getperm[perm_, n_] := Permute[IdentityMatrix[n*n], perm]
kcomm[n_] := 
 With[{mtx = ArrayReshape[Range[n*n], {n, n}]}, 
  getperm[FindPermutation[vec[Transpose[mtx]], vec[mtx]], Length[mtx]]]

nsymm[n_] := (kcomm[n] + IdentityMatrix[n^2])/2
vec[W_] := Join @@ Transpose[W];

CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct;
Clear[xx];
d = 4;
x = Array[xx, d];
sigma = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {d, d}];
sigma = sigma.Transpose[sigma] + 
  IdentityMatrix[
   d]; (* strictly posdef to avoid crash in Expectation *)
dist = 
 MultinormalDistribution[RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {d}], sigma];
Ex[expr_] := 
 Expectation[expr, 
  x \[Distributed] dist]; (* Expectation with respect to x *)

X2 = Ex[x⊗x]; (* same as sigma+mu⊗mu *)
mu = Ex[x];
Ex[(x⊗x).(x⊗x)] == Tr[X2] X2 + 2 X2.X2 - 2 mu.mu (mu⊗mu)
Ex[(x⊗x)⊗(x⊗x)] == 2 nsymm[d].(X2⊗X2) + vec[X2]⊗vec[X2] - 2 (mu⊗mu)⊗(mu⊗mu) 
Ex[(x . x)^2] == Tr[X2]^2 + 2 Tr[X2 . X2] - 2 (mu . mu)^2
```